# Как установить значение одного свойства объекта, как значение другого свойства этого же объекта? React

Tags: reactjs, объекты, state

Имеется код:

```js
class MyName extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        number: 0,
        name: 'Вася' + this.number
        }
    }
    rebder() {
      ...
    }
```

Не получается в локальном стейте присвоить свойству name число, из свойства number. Код не приведённый выше не работает. Как это сделать? Понимаю, что загвоздка скорее всего синтаксисе или контексте this, но решение так и не смог найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основной вопрос тут: зависит ли `name` только от `number`, или позже будет изменяться отдельно.

Если `name` зависит только от `number`, то его лучше не делать стейтом.

Сделайте метод: `getName(){ return 'Вася' + this.state.number }`

В данном случае вычисление не дорогое, и повышается согласованность.

Для тяжелых вычислений можно использовать `useMemo` или его аналог.

Если `name` позже будет изменяться отдельно, то в конструкторе:

```
const number = 0
const name = 'Вася' + number
this.state = { number, name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор по большей части определяет, какие названия стейтов будут у компонента, ну и их стандартное значение. Если нужно оперировать стейтами, можно это сделать в момент монтирования компонента например:

```js
class MyName extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            number: 0,
            name: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
             name: 'Вася' + this.state.number
        })
    }

    render() {
      ...
    }

}
```

Comment: как-то, по-моему, перебор для такой простой вещи в лайфсайкл залезать